# maven dependency version range not working

Tags: maven

**solved:** I was running maven from a script that had `--offline` flag hardcoded, so maven could not check what other versions were available. The error message was really really unhelpful and should be more specific...

**the original question:**

I was trying to add a version range for javassist:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>[3.29.2-GA,)</version>
</dependency>
```

...but then maven complains:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.morgwai.base:servlet-scopes:jar:10.1-SNAPSHOT-javax: Failed to collect dependencies at org.javassist:javassist:jar:[3.29.2-GA,): No versions available for org.javassist:javassist:jar:[3.29.2-GA,) within specified range -> [Help 1]

(version `3.29.2-GA` does exist and `<version>3.29.2-GA</version>` works as expected)

I guess that's somehow related to the `GA` classifier, so I've also tried this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>[3.29.2,)</version>
    <classifier>GA</classifier>
</dependency>
```

...but still not luck :(

is there a way to workaround this?

I use maven-3.9.3 in case it matters.

Comment: First why do you even use version ranges? Second which Maven version do you use? Do you have an example project?

Comment: @khmarbaise I will allow myself to ignore the inflammatory and off-topic part of your comment: you need to finally accept the way you consider as the only correct one, does not work optimally in all situations.  
Now regarding the constructive part: I use maven-3.9.3. You can create a minimal project that reproduces this problem by creating a folder with just a minimal pom.xml containing just artifact coordinates and a single dependency just as the one in the question.

Comment: @khmarbaise just solved it: you can have a look at the update